# Nomad Runtime environment and value interpolation failed to load environment value

Tags: docker, terraform, nomad, airflow

I was creating a Nomad job for airflow worker node using docker driver and trying to read from the env about the IP address or hostname of the current nomad client.

I first tried in task template, `HOST_NAME="{{ env "attr.unique.hostname" }}"` works fine and I can print out the correct host name in log.

However, when I try to fill in the config parameter such as `hostname` (https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/drivers/docker.html#hostname) using variable interpolation (https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/runtime/interpolation), such as `hostname = ${attr.unique.hostname}` I got such complaint during terraform deployment

`Invalid value for "vars" parameter: vars map does not contain key "attr",`

I also tried runtime environment (https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/runtime/environment) and fill in the config parameter such as `ipv4_address = "$NOMAD_IP_<label>:$NOMAD_HOST_PORT_<label>"` (https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/drivers/docker.html#ipv4_address). It failed to pass in the right value either.

Comment: Have you tried `hostname = "${attr.unique.hostname}"`, I know it's valid HCL without the quotes but I don't think I've ever seen nomad docs without the quotes.

Comment: strange, if I set `hostname = ${attr.unique.hostname}` it fails to parse the file entirely

Comment: could you provide the entire template, or more of it? this works for me:
    task "scheduler" {
      driver = "docker"
      env {
        hostname = "${attr.unique.hostname}"
      }

Comment: @maxm Thanks for following up! I actually have it work with `hostname = "$${attr.unique.hostname}"` inside the task -> config stanza. I think in my case, the nomad job needs an extra $ to discriminate input var from main tf file and env var